# How does voffset work in Conky?

Tags: conky

I'm trying to tweak a .conkyrc (the weather bit  [of this one](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Google-Now-366545753)) that includes (not quite) this line:

```
${image ~/.conky/google-now/images/humidity.png -p 0,155 -s 15x15}${goto 35} SOME STUFF ${voffset 15}
```

The `-p 0,155` positions the image variable. I read the documentation for [goto](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html), I know that `goto 35` prints the next element at position 35 but I don't quite know what that means. The `voffset` pushes the text down, but setting voffset to 155 doesn't seem to push the text down to the image. How do i line them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still love some kind of screen ruler thing that would make this easier, or code to report the position to the screen, but  `offset` and `voffset` adjust x or y based on your current location -- they're relative to where text would appear if you didn't offset it. `goto` is absolute -- `position 35` is 35 pixels (I might be off about the units) from the left hand margin. `offset 35` is wherever you are plus 35 pixels. Image placement (`-p 0,155`) is similarly absolute.